# Applying for "Settlement permit dependent" in Austria when on visa C

Tags: austria

I am currently employed in Austria, and I have a "Settlement permit Researcher". My wife wants to join me here. Both of us are from India. She has applied for the "National visa D" which, if she gets it, would allow her to stay with me in Austria for 6 months. Our plan was that after she comes here, she can apply for the "Settlement permit dependent". However, for some reason, embassy downgraded her application to Visa C. We know this because they asked for a particular document's copy, and in that e-mail, they have written that the application is being considered for visa C. This means that she would be able to live with me only for 3 months.

However, and more importantly, it is completely unclear to us whether she would be able to apply for the "settlement permit dependent" while she is on visa C.

[This link](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/en/themen/leben_in_oesterreich/aufenthalt/3/1/Seite.120222.html#inl) seems to suggest that because I am on "Researcher permit", she can indeed apply for it after a lawful entry to Austria, but it is not very clear to us. Any help related to this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the time to answer yet but a D visa will allow your wife to get the permit, a C visa **will not** allow her to apply for the permit

Comment: @NicolasFormichella there are exceptions to that rule, and I agree with Peaceful that it is not clear from the linked page whether this would be one of the exceptions.  The question belongs on [Expatriates.SE], though.